# mysql UDF : fopen = permission denied

Tags: mysql, permissions, database, fopen

this is question [I already asked on SO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html) but I wonder if this could be a SysAdmin problem.

I'm trying to create a [mysql UDF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html) , this function calls "fopen/fclose" to read a flat file stored in `/data`. But using errno (yes, I know it is bad in a MT program...) I can see that the function cannot open my file:

```
"Permission denied"
```

I tried to do a

```
chmod -R 755 /data (as well as 777, chown -R mysql:mysql /data etc...)
```

but it didn't change anything.

when I copied the flat file to /tmp : OK, my UDF was able to 'fopen' the file. I'm puzzled.

currently , I've got:

```
drwxrwxrwx 4 pierre root 4096 2010-05-26 16:51 /data
drwxrwxrwx 3 pierre root 4096 2010-05-18 09:41 /data/dir1
drwxrwxrwx 3 pierre root 4096 2010-05-18 09:41 /data/dir1/dir2
drwxrwxrwx 4 pierre root 4096 2010-05-18 10:27 /data/dir1/dir2/dir3
-rw-r--r-- 1 pierre root 50685268 2005-12-10 00:01 /data/dir1/dir2/dir3/myfile.txt
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqld was protected by [apparmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor).

> AppArmor represents one of several
>   possible approaches to the problem of
>   restricting the actions that installed
>   software can take.

I added

```
/data/** r,
```

at the end of

```
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

apparmor was restarted:

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

and now my UDF works fine ! :-)